# Unsupported Version of OpenGL

Tags: games, steam, opengl, mesa, amdgpu

I have been playing Dying Light that last few days without problems then all of a sudden I get this error message starting 6-21-17

```
Unsupported Version of OpenGL!
Detected OpenGL version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3
Required OpenGL version: 3.3
Please update your display driver.
```

System Specs

I'm running the latest Steam client.

Ubuntu 17.04 with the latest updates... 
I even patched the kernel to 4.11.6-041106-generic but that didn't work.

AMD RX580 using the opensource drivers.

I am also running the latest mesa using 
https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa/

and I also tried this but this didn't work either
https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa/

```
glxinfo | grep version
```

gives the following

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.0.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So i got Dying Light working perfect and here is how.

Install Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 (or any other Ubuntu 16.04.2 distro) because that is the only OS supported by the AMD proprietary drivers

Install the AMD proprietary drivers 17.10 for my RX580
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

Thats it... Dying light works great!